# Which events should I use that can accurately record page access time and page departure time in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to record some info in native app's open webview, close webview; h5's history.push, history.goback()
which events should i use?

Comment: You can start timer in constructor or componentDidMount.
And clear the timer in componentWillUnmount, make sure you save the timer value before clearing.